# postgresql: use result from aggregate auxiliary function in select

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

In an auxiliary function, I use an aggegate function (`count`) thus it gives only a single result, no column.
Later, I want to use the function's result in my query:

```
with total as  (select count(*) from employees)
select emp_no, (cast (rank() over (order by emp_no) as Float))/total
from employees
```

However, this yields an error:

> column "total" does not exist

I interpret the error as: the single (aggregate) result need to be converted into a column. How can I solve this? Is there a way to solve this (efficiently)?

I read multiple references about `WITH` (e.g. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_with_clause.htm) but there is always a table created in the `WITH` clause., not a single value as in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but there is always a table created in the WITH clause., not a single value as in my case.

A CTE **always** creates a "table". Even your CTE - it just so happens that your CTE always contains exactly one column and one row.

---

The cause of the error is the fact that your final query doesn't reference the CTE named `total`, and therefor it can't access it (or its column).

You need to include the CTE `total` in the `from` clause of your final SELECT statement:

```
with total as (
  select count(*) as emp_count
  from employees
)
select emp_no, (cast (rank() over (order by emp_no) as Float)) / emp_count
from employees
  cross join total;
```

You could simplify the expression in the final SELECT, if you cast the count to a number (or float) type:

```
with total as (
  select count(*)::float as emp_count
  from employees
)
select emp_no, 
       rank() over (order by emp_no) / emp_count
from employees
  cross join total;
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a reason to use cross join instead of a comma?

Comment: That's the same thing.